# How to give range for Auto_Increment in MySql?

Tags: mysql

How to give range (i.e. from 10 20 30) for auto increment in mysql?

```
ALTER TABLE role_t AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Comment: Anything particularly wrong with your query?

Comment: If you need to mess around with an auto increment, then you probably should not be using it!